# How is VS/TypeScript telling me Object is possibly null?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2019, null-check

I've got the following TypeScript snippet:

```
const anchorRef = React.useRef(null);
...
const handleClose = (event: any): void => {
        if (anchorRef != null && anchorRef.current != null && anchorRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
            return;
        }
        setOwnState({ ...ownState, open: false });
    }

...
<Popper placement='top' id='id-popper' open={ownState.open} anchorEl={anchorRef.current} transition disablePortal>
...
```

Visual Studio is telling me that Object is possibly null @

```
anchorRef.current.contains
```

[image]

Since I'm doing all the necessary null checking prior to hitting that, how is that even possible?

Edit 1:
Currently anchorRef.current only ever is null, but at the point where it is giving me an error, it has been checked for null.  I don't really care that, right now, it only ever is null.  I just want to get rid of the TS error.

Comment: What if you change the first condition to `!== null`?

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [ask].

Comment: might be better to use `if(anchorRef && anchorRef.current ......`

Comment: no change if  using !==.  Also no change with if(anchorRef && anchorRef.current...

Comment: If I actually initialize it to be something other than null, the error goes away. However, my question isn't really about the actual value of the object, but rather, why the null checking isn't being observed by visual studio.